# Multiple Vue apps, shared components in a monorepo

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

We have two key user types for our system, and we would like to break out the apps into two separate folders in a single repo. The idea then would be to have a shared components lib which both projects could use.

I am looking for some guidance on the best practice for how to achieve such a setup, ideally we can satisfy the following:

- each app in a separate folder
- shared lib, maybe using github packages
- shared configuration file
- storybook running in the shared lib folder

Answer (score 1):

I have limited experience, but it seems that for pnpm a common setup is:

```
mkdir <repo-name>
cd <repo-name>
pnpm init
mkdir packages
mkdir apps
```

**pnpm-workspace.yaml**

```yaml
packages:
  - "packages/**"
  - "apps/**"
```

**.npmrc**

```
shamefully-hoist=true
```

**.gitignore**

```
node_modules
```

**package.json**

Rename the name to this format: `"name":"@<repo-name>/root"`

Applications go into the "apps" folder, reusable packages en components go into the "packages" folder.

I cannot comment on storybook.